# Which type of spline should be used (package mgcv)?

Tags: r, spline, gam, mgcv

Consider the code below:

```
library(mgcv) 
x1 = runif(50)
x2 = sample(1:10, 50, replace=T)
y = rnorm(50)
m = gam(y~s(x1)+s(x2))
```

Here are my questions:

1. How can we extract (not determine) the type of spline and also the number of knots used for that?
2. In general, how can we choose the proper type of spline? (for available spline types we can look at `?smooth.terms`). In the above example, `x1` has large number of distinct values, while `x2` has only 10 distinct number of distinct values at maximum. Should we use the same type of spline for both? **Which criteria should be considered for choosing the type of spline in general?**

Comment: If you have questions about modelling data, you should be asking at [stats.se] or [datascience.se]. Stack overflow is for specific programming questions. So part 2 seems to be off topic for this site. For part 1, what exactly are you after when you say "type" of spline? What is the desired output?

Comment: @MrFlick I think the first question is obvious if we look at `?smooth.terms`: a variety of spline types are available in package mgcv (i.e. `bs="cr"`, `bs="tp"`, ... ). I just want to know the code I can use to know which type of spline is used by default in my specified model . More importantly, I also need to know the number of knots used to build it.

Comment: The specification of the model type comes from the formula. The `s()` function defaults to `bs="tp"` (ie "thin plane") per the documentation.

Comment: Thank you, and what about the number of knots?